# Yii Asset manager - css with image url

Tags: css, yii, assets, broken-image

I am using the following code to publish my css file to assets.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile( Yii::app()->assetManager->publish( Yii::getPathOfAlias('application').'/../css/combo-autocomplete.css' ));
```

It registers the css successfully and styles are working fine, but the following css class using a image.

```
.ui-icon {
   background-image: url(../images/down-arrow.png); 
}
```

is not loading, it is referred to path inside assets folder. It is looking for the image inside

> root/assets/images/

Is there any way to redirect the image url in the css to the original path, because i am not registering my images as assets as of now.

> root/images

Comment: It doesn't make that much sense to publish your CSS as an asset but leave your images bare. Either you are designing a self-contained component (in which case publish everything) or you don't (in which case publish nothing).

Comment: @Jon, if i publish images to assets, it will not keep the same folder name (images) inside my assets folder. it will be like `/root/assets/4s431e/icon.png` ?

Comment: I expanded the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yii's asset manager is designed to let you package components such as UI widgets in a self-contained manner (the alternative being to manually distribute various files in different places inside your application directory structure). So if it makes sense to publish *anything* as an asset from your component, it makes sense to publish *everything* as an asset.

In that case, you should structure your component e.g. as

```
component/
    assets/
        css/
        images/
        js/
```

Then, publish the whole `assets/` directory using Yii's asset manager instead of publishing files one by one. If you do this, they will end up being published in a manner like

```
assets/
    random_hash/
        css/
        images/
```

Your CSS can then simply refer to images with `url(../images/image.jpg)` without needing to know the value of `random_hash`.

Comment: My css not not sees images (( In random_hash/ is only css file.