# How to properly use and store images in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I think someone has already asked the question about where the best or how to store images that are used in the code and CSS.

I personally keep it all in the folder: **/protetsted /components/assets/images/**

Use the code as follows:

```
$loadingImage = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.components.assets.images').'/ajax-loader.gif');
```

But I think it is somehow wrong and too complicated.

Or how to use the image data to the CSS?

**p.s.** I beg your pardon for probably a very stupid

Comment: I couldn't answer better than this guy did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954203/yii-asset-manager-css-with-image-url#12954773

Comment: You can make a new alias with `Yii::setPathOfAlias($alias, $path)` to shorten the string. From `application.components.assets.images` to `images_path` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to store the images is to save the images in the root directory so as you can call the images as

```
echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/images/01.jpg', 'alt 1');
```

Comment: it was I who did just that) Thank you.

Comment: Is it easier now using Yii 2.0?